# Reflection about the line $y = x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

This concept is new to me. I am doing a university level class and the way this class is presented is very theoretical that I even struggle to read the symbols (except in a very slow way). Because of this concepts that I thought I previously understood and how they interrelate, I suddenly feel like I don't understand, and am getting them confused (e.g., one to one, increasing/decreasing, monotonicity, etc etc).

The question I am struggling with is:

Consider the function, $f(x) = x^3 -4$ and take its reflection in the line $y = x$.

Because $f(x)$ is monotone we know that its reflection describes the graph of another function $g(x)$.

What is its formula?

So I have managed (I think) to take the reflection in the line $y = x$:

$f(x) = x^{\frac13} - 4$, but I am really unsure how to proceed from here.

Could someone help me understand this and how it is related to increasing across the domain?

Comment: This is equivalent to the inverse, $f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: Thank you. Given that the inverse is $y = (x + 4) ^ (1/3)$: what does the question mean by this function (i.e., ```y = (x + 4) ^ (1/3)```) describes another additional function , what is its g(x)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given:

$f(x)=x^3-4$ or $y=x^3-4$

for reflection of any function $f(x)$ about the line $y=x$, exchange  $x$ & $y$ or put $y=x$ and $x=y$ in given function $f(x)$

$$x=y^3-4$$

$$y^3=x+4$$

$$y=(x+4)^{1/3}$$
above function is reflection of $f(x) $ about line y=x

Answer (score 2):

Reflection over $y = x$ is the same thing as just switching $y$ and $x$. The point $(1, 1)$ stays the same, for example, but $(2, 1)$ becomes $(1, 2)$ and vise versa. So $x = y^3 - 4, \,y^3 = x + 4$ and assuming real numbers, $y = (x + 4)^{1/3}$.

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).